# Magento 2 : How to create new skeleton module using Bash script?

Tags: magento2, module

I am looking for an bash script which will create the basic new module skeleton. I've found this [post](https://shakyaabiral.wordpress.com/2019/09/04/bash-script-to-create-a-new-skeleton-module-in-magento-2/) useful but it only works from the root. Any solution?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If your goal is to create modules quickly and not neccesarly trough a bash script you should take a look at https://mage2gen.com/

Comment: @CarloRicci Thanks I often use it, but looking specifically for shell script.